# SP - Error occurred in deployment step 'Recycle IIS Application Pool' in VS

Tags: sharepoint-server, visual-studio, error, solution-deployment

I have a privileges everywhere, but where i deploy a project with webParts, Visual studio, show me following **error** :

> Error 1   Error occurred in deployment step 'Recycle IIS Application Pool': Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

How to solve this proble. Thank you previously!

Answer (score 1):

- Make sure that you are running the Visual Studio as Administrator.
- Make sure the application pool of SharePoint web application is running.
- Check the Site Url of your SharePoint Solution and make sure you assigned it properly and correctly ,

> Right click on solution name > Properties > Check Site URL

- Try to remove your solution from central administration .
- Check if the SharePoint timer service is running.
- Make sure that the  "Package" folder is exist in your solution explorer.

  - if not exist make sure that it's not excluded from the solution then include it
  - else try to create a new solution and move your web part